# jade conditional unexpected token illegal

Tags: pug

Im building a small application with express, node, and jade.  I am trying to get this to work:

```
    if user
      p Welcome, #{user.fullName} 
      p
      .div(style={position: 'absolute', right: '150px', top: '75px'})
        unless #{user.email} == "someemail@gmail.com"
          a.btn.btn-primary(href="/upload") Upload New Schedule
          br
        br
        a.btn.btn-primary(href="/logout") Logout
```

I tried running the above and it is giving an error on the line:

```
        unless #{user.email} == "someemail@gmail.com"
```

Unexpected token ILLEGAL at Function ()

Any ideas on what is going on? Everything is indented by the way. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the answer? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
unless #{user.email} == "someemail@gmail.com"
```

to

```
unless user.email == "someemail@gmail.com"
```

run it

```
$ cat test.jade && jade test.jade && cat test.html
- var user={fullName:'me',email:'me@here.org'}
if user
  p Welcome, #{user.fullName} 
  p
  .div(style={position: 'absolute', right: '150px', top: '75px'})
    unless user.email == "someemail@gmail.com"
      a.btn.btn-primary(href="/upload") Upload New Schedule
      br
    br
    a.btn.btn-primary(href="/logout") Logout
  rendered test.html

<p>Welcome, me </p><p></p><div style="position:absolute;right:150px;top:75px" class="div"><a href="/upload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload New Schedule</a><br/><br/><a href="/logout" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a></div>
```

You'll have to make sure that user is defined, otherwise the conditional part will be rendered always